# clip aerial map from Add Basemap Imagery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, clip, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

I wish to clip an aerial image from the "Imagery" of Add Basemap in Arcmap 10.3 and save as a sid file.
How can I do that? Can someone help me please.

Example, I am looking to clip only the state of Minnesota from the "Imagery" of add basemap.

Comment: You cannot clip the basemap image services provided with ArcMap.  These files are connected to via the internet, and do not reside on your local computer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the [Terms of Use](http://www.esri.com/legal/software-license) don't allow this.  There is a [summary](http://downloads2.esri.com/ArcGISOnline/docs/tou_summary.pdf) of the Terms of Use available.  In particular, note:

> YOU MAY
>
> > Use the basemap data offline in the following manner
> >
> > - The data may only be taken offline using Esri Content Packages
>
> YOU MAY NOT
>
> > Systematically harvest map tiles through any method other than using Esri Content Packages

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Luke, there is a way around you can do that. Just open ArcMap and while you are in the Data view. You can set up your scale you wish but keep in mind when you export the quality may or may not be as good as it is.

So, from ArcMap, go to File menu and scroll down to Export Map. Choose what you want to save as type. There is actually no mrsid to save it but there are others such as jpeg, tiff, and so on.

Ensure you enable checkbox "Write World File"

for more info go here : http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/map-export-and-print/exporting-your-map.htm

You can clip them and keep them to yourself and not to display them on your map, because on the imagery you will stils see  ESRI source stamp on their basemap on the lower right corner.

Comment: my answer only refers to ripping full resolution imagery. The Terms of Use specifically *include* permission to grab low res versions like discussed in your answer - "YOU MAY Include screen captures or a printed or plotted maps in the following ways: Personal use, internal business use, or include in a presentation or a report for a client"

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I am actually looking to extract clipped aerial image in an applicable format so that I can use it in Microstation or AutoCad. Any idea how I could do that so that I have spatial attributes on that image?

Comment: No, but have you google it ? If you are stuck I would suggest you to try and post the same question here  https://geonet.esri.com/welcome  you might find a lot of respond from there. Have you post the same thing in Microstation or Autocad ? Good luck

Comment: @OzKhan if you follow PROBERTs instructions, your output will be georeferenced (i.e "have spatial attributes"). It will just be low resolution.